# Cocoa Touch - Display an Activity Indicator while loading a UITabBar View

Tags: iphone, multithreading, cocoa-touch, uitabbar, nsnotificationcenter

I have a UITabBar Application with two views that load large amounts of data from the web in their "viewWillAppear" methods. I want to show a progress bar or an activity indicator while this data is being retrieved, to make sure the user knows the app isn't frozen.

I am aware that this has been asked before. I simply need some clarification on what seems to be a rather [good solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109351).

I have implimented the code in the example. The question's original asker later solved their problem, by putting the retrieval of data into another "thread". I understand the concept of threads, but I do not know how I would impliment this.

With research, I have found that I need to move all of my heavy data retrieval into a background thread, as all of the UI updating occurs in the main thread.

If one would be so kind as to provide an example for me, I would be very appreciative. I can provide parts of my existing code as necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use NSURLConnection it runs on another thread automatically.

in your viewDidLoad:

```
NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:theURL];
NSURLConnection *conn = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:req delegate:self];
```

then you need some custom methods. If you type in `-connection` and press Esc you'll see all the different methods you can use. There are three you will need with this:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    // this is called when there is a response
        // if you're collecting data init your NSMutableData here
}

-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    // each time the connection downloads a 
        // packet of data it gets send here
        // so you can do [myData appendData:data];
} 

- (void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
        // the connection has finished so you can 
        // do what you want with the data here
}
```

That is basically all there is to it. NSURLConnection handles all the multithreading itself and you don't have to worry. Now you can create an activity indicator and display it and it will work because the main thread is empty. :)

Comment: Ok. I'll try this out. Right now, I'm using [Data dataWithContentsOfURL:URL].

Comment: Another thing: I actually want to to do the data loading in "viewWillAppear", as the data from the sources I'm loading can change dramatically. I also support username switching, which means that the page I'm loading can change between displaying views in a multitude of scenarios. Will the NSURLConnection method still work in the viewWillAppear function? Thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: yeah... it can work anywhere... you could put those two lines in your own custom method and call it whenever you want from wherever you want. With username switching I would probably even go further and say that you would want this in a custom class and instead of relying on `viewWillAppear` when the user switches username and function you call a method in your custom object which then reruns this. Its a bit neater and more reliable, and you have more control.

Comment: WHOAH! THIS IS AWESOME! The view loads instantaneously, then it dumps the content. This makes things so much more... responsive! Thanks for the help. I never understood what all the fuss was about things like "lazy loading". Now I do.

Comment: But now I have an EXC_BAD_ACCESS on an NSDictionary that I didn't release. You wouldn't happen to know how that could happen, would you?

Comment: how are you declaring it? if you use `[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:]` or similar (ie: without `alloc init`) then its autoreleased every run cycle. You need to do `[myDictionary retain]` to stop this happening, but be aware this will put your retain count up. I'm guessing its a global variable? give it `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDictionary *theDictionary;` and then when you set it use `self.theDictionary = whatever;` which will automatically retain it.

Comment: I had it defined like you said, but adding [dictionary retain] fixed the problem lickety split! Thanks for being so patient with an objective-c newbie :)

Comment: Indeed. Memory Management in Objective-C is so easy compared to all that malloc, dealloc stuff...